# What is the difference between this PHP code and the Python code for encryption?

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to replicate the following PHP code in PYTHON. This code works perfectly and the result is correct.

```
<?php
class RESTfulAPI {
    function __construct($DomainOrIP, $Key, $Secret) {
        $this->BaseUri = $DomainOrIP ."/X/X/";
        $this->ApiKey = $Key;
        $this->ApiSecret = $Secret;
        // Encryption vector initialization
        $this->SecretIV = substr(hash("SHA256", $this->ApiKey, true), 0, 16);
        
    }

    function base64Url_Encode($data) {
        $encoded = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');

        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }

        // Encryption for properties
        function APIEncryptData($Data) {
            echo $this->SecretIV;
            $output = openssl_encrypt($Data, "AES-256-CBC", md5($this->ApiSecret),
                OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->SecretIV);
            return $this->base64Url_Encode($output);
        }
    
}

$ApiKey = "X";
$ApiSecret = "X";
$API = new RESTfulAPI("https://XXX", $ApiKey, $ApiSecret);
$Endpoint = 'userRead';
$Data =  '{"id":"79"}';

// Llamar a la función y capturar el resultado a través de la instancia
$resultado = $API->base64Url_Encode($Data);

$resultado2 = $API->APIEncryptData($Data);

// Imprimir el resultado
echo $resultado . " \n";

echo $resultado2;
?>
```

The replica of this code in Python is as follows, however I find that the result differs between Python and PHP

```
import hashlib
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
import requests
import json

class RESTfulAPI:
    def __init__(self, DomainOrIP, Key, Secret):
        self.BaseUri = f"{DomainOrIP}/X/X/"
        self.ApiKey = Key.encode()
        self.ApiSecret = Secret.encode()
        self.SecretIV = hashlib.sha256(self.ApiKey).digest()[:16]

    def base64Url_Encode(self, data):
        encoded = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data)
        return encoded.rstrip(b'=').decode('utf-8')

    def APIEncryptData(self, Data):
        cipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(self.ApiSecret).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, self.SecretIV)
        padded_data = pad(Data.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size)
        encrypted = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
        return self.base64Url_Encode(encrypted)

    def _pad_data(self, data):
        block_size = AES.block_size
        padding_size = block_size - len(data) % block_size
        padding = bytes([padding_size] * padding_size)
        return data + padding

# Ejemplo de uso del constructor
API = RESTfulAPI("https://XXX", "X", "X")

data_to_encode = '{"id":"79"}'
encoded_data = API.base64Url_Encode(data_to_encode.encode('utf-8'))
print("Encoded Data:", encoded_data)

encrypted_data = API.APIEncryptData(data_to_encode)
print("Encrypted Data:", encrypted_data)
```

the result in PHP "9Snlo8eZr1iXb55lYJqUjw" but in PYthon "Bzr0stuTxBPmJ3qpHfmyJw". I found the error in the APIEncryptData function, since the rest of the code apparently gives me the same data.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: In both PHP and Python generate consistent results for the "Encoded Data" given that they are using the same base64 URL-safe encoding functions. The base64 URL-safe encoding ensures that the special characters + and / are replaced with - and _, respectively, and any trailing = characters are removed.

Comment: have you narrowed down which step the results start to differ? e.g. is it at `padded_data` or `encrypted` or only after `base64Url_Encode`

Comment: only after base64Url_Encode in the APIEncryptedData

Comment: if I `print(f"{encrypted=}")` in Python (the line before `self.base64Url_Encode(encrypted)`) I get `encrypted=b"\x07:\xf4\xb2\xdb\x93\xc4\x13\xe6'z\xa9\x1d\xf9\xb2'"`.  In PHP (using https://onlinephp.io/ PHP 8.2.9) if I `echo base64_encode(b"\x07:\xf4\xb2\xdb\x93\xc4\x13\xe6'z\xa9\x1d\xf9\xb2'");` then I get `Bzr0stuTxBPmJ3qpHfmyJw==` which matches the Python output before stripping the `==`

Comment: The results match if in the Python code `digest()` is replaced by `hexdigest().encode('ascii')` regarding the MD5 hash value.

Comment: It is of course a vulnerability to blow up a 16 bytes value by hex encoding to 32 bytes and use it as key.

Comment: @Topaco I would like to learn more about this vulnerability, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Anentropic - Take a look at [this article](https://www.ubiqsecurity.com/three-common-encryption-mistakes-that-are-easy-to-avoid/), section *Common Encryption Mistake #1*.

Comment: It appears that the result has differed based on the new comments on the entry @Topaco

Comment: You are right, my mistake